# Python: (Count positive and negative numbers and compute the average of numbers)

Tags: python, nested-loops, python-3.4

> Problem statement: Write a program that reads an unspecified number of integers, determines how many positive and negative values have been read, and computes the total and average of the input values (not counting zeros). Your program ends with the input 0. Display the average as a floating-point number.

Sample output (ignore bullets, didn't know how to format text into console output):

- Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: 1
- Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: 2
- Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: -1
- Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: 3
- Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: 0
- You didn't enter any number
- The number of positives is 3
- The number of negatives is 1
- The total is 5
- The average is 1.25

Attempted solution:

```
def main():
    i = int( input ("Enter an interger, the input ends if it is 0: "))
    count_pos = 0
    count_neg = 0
    total = 0
    if (i != 0):
        while (i != 0):
            if (i > 0):
                count_pos += 1
            elif (i < 0):
                count_neg += 1
            total += i
            i = int( input ("Enter an interger, the input ends if it is 0: "))
            count = count_pos + count_neg
            average = total / count

        print ("The number of positives is", count_pos)
        print ("The number of negatives is", count_neg)
        print ("The total is", total)
        print ("The average is", float(average))
    else:
        print ("You didn't enter any number.")

main()
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: The problem statement is at the top in the block that is labelled with "Problem statement: "

Comment: What errors do you get in your output?

Comment: NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: Just a warning, using `eval` on user input is extremely dangerous and should probably never be done.

Comment: @IanAuld I kep being told this? Why is using eval dangerous?

Comment: `eval` is more than dangerous, it's evil as far I am concerned. What `eval` does is execute any arbitrary Python code you pass it. So if a user was to input `import os;os.listdir(os.getcwd())` that code would be executed so the user could see the contents of your current working directory. They would be able to move about your file system at will and delete/copy/move things as if they were you. `eval` is extremely dangerous and if you ever find yourself thinking you should use it you should very carefully consider if you are doing the rihgt thing.

Comment: @DanielSchulze it also doesn't do anything if you pass it a number. It is totally unnecessary in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need this line (which is why your error is happening):

```
main(i)
```

To continuously get user input, use an infinite loop, and test for the condition to break the loop.

```
while (true):
    i = input("Enter an integer (0 to stop): ")
    if(i == 0)
        break
    sum1 += i
    if (i > 0):
      count_pos += 1
    elif (i < 0):
      count_neg += 1
```

Then calculate and return average.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the main function with the parameter 'i', which does not exist. You can't use variables declared in a function outside of that function

Check out: [Python Scopes](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/scope_resolution_legb_rule.ipynb)